# Can somebody help me translate CASE statement with dates?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I need to modify a Stored Procedure, and I cant understand how day manipulate those dates in a WHERE clause. Especially when END=1. I have never see that before.

```
 CASE WHEN @DateFrom IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE
                        CASE WHEN INV.InvoiceDate > INV.EffectiveDate THEN 
                            CASE WHEN dateDiff(d, @DateFrom, INV.InvoiceDate) >= 0 
                                AND dateDiff(d, @DateTo, INV.InvoiceDate) <= 0 Then 1 else 0 end
                        ELSE
                            CASE WHEN dateDiff(d, @DateFrom, INV.EffectiveDate) >= 0 
                                AND dateDiff(d, @DateTo, INV.EffectiveDate) <= 0 Then 1 else 0 end
                        END 
                        END = 1
```

Comment: It's just a series of conditions that give your `CASE` *expression* a value of 1 or 0. After all of this, the whole `CASE WHEN ..... END` returns either 0 or 1 and then you are saying that you only want rows where that `CASE` expression is 1

Answer (score 0):

when you convert it into single case it seems easier to understand:

```
CASE 
        WHEN @DateFrom IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN @DateFrom IS NOT NULL  AND dateDiff(d, @DateFrom, INV.InvoiceDate) >= 0 AND dateDiff(d, @DateTo, INV.InvoiceDate) <= 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END =1
```

you could also try this

```
CASE 
    WHEN @DateFrom IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 
                        (CASE 
                        WHEN dateDiff(d, @DateFrom, INV.InvoiceDate) >= 0 AND dateDiff(d, @DateTo, INV.InvoiceDate) <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
                        END)
            END)
            END = 1
```

what i'm getting at is the second level of this case is weird. the `when` and `else` cases are the same, so it doesn't need to be there.

```
(CASE 
        WHEN INV.InvoiceDate > INV.EffectiveDate
        THEN (CASE 
                    WHEN dateDiff(d, @DateFrom, INV.InvoiceDate) >= 0 AND dateDiff(d, @DateTo, INV.InvoiceDate) <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
                    END)
        ELSE (CASE 
                WHEN dateDiff(d, @DateFrom, INV.EffectiveDate) >= 0 AND dateDiff(d, @DateTo, INV.EffectiveDate) <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the number of returning records is different when using your version. And honestly, its not a first time I am trying to substitute this CASE statement with more ..like.. easy to read one, but nothing works. I mean other ones do not return same number of records

Comment: made some changes to the answer, but not sure why it gave you different results.

Answer (score 0):

This one is gives an error. I think parenthesis is missing somewhere

```
 CASE 
        WHEN @DateFrom IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 
                            (CASE 
                            WHEN dateDiff(d, @DateFrom, INV.InvoiceDate) >= 0 AND dateDiff(d, @DateTo, INV.InvoiceDate) <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
                            END)
                END)
                END = 1
```

[image]